# Target a single image with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Is it possible to target a single image with htaccess in order to specify the cache expiration, or can you only target groups by their file extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - wrap your [mod_expires](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html) directives within a [`<Files>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#files) or similar directive that targets only the file or files that you wish to have a special expiration policy set on.

I just tested this, and that it does work within `.htaccess`:

```
<Files "test1.txt">
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault A60
</Files>
```

This resulted in the following HTTP response headers for this file and only this file (other files were not given these headers at all):

```
Cache-Control: max-age=60
Expires: Sat, 21 Jan 2012 19:45:40 GMT
```

(Somewhat related to https://serverfault.com/questions/173462/mod-expires-exclude-a-single-directory.)